# Is there a way to import a text file and display it onto the webpage but also make specific changes to each line on the text file?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to import a text file (not user import), for example:

> Coding
>
> There are several languages...

When the file is read, the first line should be in larger font and bolded, and the other lines can be kept in the text file format. I'm not sure if Javascript or something similar would work in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply modify the content from the file using [RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and/or
[String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to manipulate as needed.

A basic, rudimentary demo:

```js
const process = () => {
  // some file content with line breaks
  const fileContent = 'line 1\nline 2\nline 3';

  const contentEditor = document.querySelector('#content');

  // very basic example of processing:
  // grab the first line using a regex
  let re = /(.*)\n/mi;
  // replace the matching with new surrounding content
  let edited = fileContent.replace(re, '<h1><b>$1</b></h1>\n');

  // replace breaks with <p>
  re = /\n(.*)/gim;
  edited = edited.replace(re, '<p>$1</p>');

  // display
  contentEditor.innerHTML = edited;

  console.info(edited);
}

window.addEventListener('load', process, false);
```

```css
#content {
  min-height: 50vh;
  background: AliceBlue;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: I tried that snippet of code, however, I get the error:
`
const contentEditor = document.querySelector('#content');
                      ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
`

Comment: Code in the snippet runs as expected. If you are not running in the browser, then `document.querySelector('#content');` will error as `document` will not exist. You need to adjust to your environment but you have tagged the question with 'html' and 'javascript'.